# YouTube API .loadVideoById() fails in IE9 and IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, youtube-api, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I could have sworn that this worked at one point, but I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this. I load the YouTube API asynchronously. I call the onReady function() to create a Player instance with a video ID and all is well.

Now mix in to this scenario, a list of other videos that I want to load in to the same Player instance if they're clicked. Doing this by utilizing the `player.loadVideoById(videoID);` works, no problem, in everything but IE9 and IE10. In IE9 and IE10, I get a can't load this video error. The only workaround that I've seen for this is destroying the Player instance and recreating it with the constructor. But I hate doing this when loadVideoById() should do.

Has anyone run in to this problem? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide sample code for us to replicate?

Comment: @TimWintle - May I send you a complete example via email? I'll be more than happy to post (or accept) any answer that comes out of your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the Flash player rather than the HTML5 one - the latter is not supported for that function.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3813

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I did what the commenters of the issue did. Destroyed the player and created it again. Which sucks, but works.